# Should I avoid the session with a complex object in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, session

Here's my issue, we have a large patient object that is used on multiple screens throughout the admin. Each screen contains different information about the same patient. It can't all be on one screen.

The only time I want to persist the patient is when the user clicks save. I need to have an in memory patient somewhere. A user may be in the admin, change patient information on various screens, run validation and decide to not save that patient. This is typical use.

Is it ok to store this patient in the session? Or, is there a better approach to do this? At most this admin would have 20 users with access.

Answer (score 0):

Opinions may vary on this.  Session is tricky, especially if you use something other than in-memory session.  Distributed session will break a non-serializable object.  If this object is a simple POCO or object you control, try your best to make it play with serialization.  If it does you're set.  For an admin tool without much load I'd say you'd be fine.

Hey I found this - know nothing about the site, but illustrates my point:
https://www.fortify.com/vulncat/en/vulncat/dotnet/asp_dotnet_bad_practices_non_serializable_object_stored_in_session.html

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation with similar amount of users. I did it and it worked great.

My situation was about scheduling events.

Someone would create an event and through multiple web pages would modify and configure this event.  When they were all done it would save all the details to SQL.  In the end, I was surprised just how well it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Session should be fine here. You have what appears to be a light user load... but you might want to check exactly how much memory the object takes up, multiply that by the maximum number of users, and see where you are.

If you want to avoid the session altogether, you could use System.Web.Caching to store the object instead, and key the stored object using the users identifier plus some constant string.

In either case, you'll want to be aware of how many web servers are running the application. If it's just one web server, no worries. If you have multiple web servers, you'll want to make sure they are "sticky" - then the user is guaranteed to have all requests processed by the same server. How this is done is entirely dependent on your flavor of load balancing... normally the "IT folks" handle this for you.